# Ionic Angular JS $routeProvider loading ion-list won't scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an `ion-content` tag with ng-view which is pulling in partials using a routeProvider. Each partial is loading a list from an XML API and this is all working flawlessly, except the lists are completely unscrollable.

I've tried using `ion-scroll` (which works, but when you release, it scrolls back to the top of the list), as well as `scroll="true"` and `overflow-scroll="true"`.

Nothing works. Here's some code:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper header">
        <i class="icon ion-android-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.$" />
    </label>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content class="has-header" data-ng-view overflow-scroll="true"></ion-content>
```

And here's an example of a partial (They all follow exactly the same structure.)

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item data-ng-repeat="route in routes | filter:search" data-ng-click="showRoute(route)">{{route._title}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Here is the script:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/route-list.html',
            controller: 'RouteListController'
        })
        .when('/route', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/stop-list.html',
            controller: 'StopListController'
        })
        .when('/stop', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/prediction.html',
            controller: 'PredictionController'
        });
    });
```

Testing on iPhone 4S Simulated. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a div with the ng-view directive inside ion-content

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
  <div data-ng-view></div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: This works, but now when the ng-view changes, the scrollbar position stays the same. If the next list is shorter than the previous, the user has to manually scroll back up to see any content. I'm accepting your answer because it did solve my problem, but do you have any idea why this next issue is occurring?

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/. You should call $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop() on each controller. BTW look into using $stateProvider. Here's a good starter template: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu. It manages the scroll position between page changes

Comment: Thanks, ionicScrollDelegate worked perfectly.

Is there any benefit to using $stateProvider other than the $routeProvider approach i've taken?